# Capacitor 3 and has no exported member PushNotification

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

I have recently updated my Ionic Project with Capacitor from version 2 to 3.

I am getting the following errors, it seems it's related to the Notification messages plugin from the capacitor. Can someone advise how I can solve this issue?

```
    ERROR in src/app/myaccount/myaccount.page.ts:38:3 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../node_modules/@capacitor/core/types"' has no exported member 'PushNotification'.
[ng] 38   PushNotification,
[ng]      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] src/app/myaccount/myaccount.page.ts:39:3 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../node_modules/@capacitor/core/types"' has no exported member 'PushNotificationToken'.
[ng] 39   PushNotificationToken,
[ng]      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] src/app/myaccount/myaccount.page.ts:40:3 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../node_modules/@capacitor/core/types"' has no exported member 'PushNotificationActionPerformed'.
[ng] 40   PushNotificationActionPerformed } from '@capacitor/core';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In capacitor 3, the way of import is different. More like a common npm package.

Old way:

```
// OLD
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { AnyPlugin } = Plugins;
```

New way:

```
// NEW
import { AnyPlugin } from 'any-plugin';
```

Also, check the [documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0#backward-incompatible-plugin-changes) page for updating to 3.0 and to know the incompatible plugin changes.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I made changes to the project. It compiles well, when i use Ionic Serve.

But on Android Studio, it builds successfully, but not APK files are being generated .

What can i check on Android Studio to make sure things are right?

Gradle Version is set to 7 and Android Grade Plugin Version is 4

Comment: Hmm, weird! In your project go to: `Android > app > build > outputs > apk `
thats the folder where the apk is stored. 

i usually run `ionic capacitor build android`, and in android studio i just run it in my physical device